# Varnish Error: vcl.load /etc/varnish/default.vcl failed

Tags: linux, caching, ubuntu, varnish, varnish-vcl

On executing the command

```
sudo service varnish reload
```

I;m getting the following error:

```
nish@styx:~$ sudo service varnish reload
 * Reloading HTTP accelerator varnishd         
Connection failed (localhost:1234)
Error: vcl.load fc6eef74-6802-4f71-987f-7e6f2bbd8405 /etc/varnish/default.vcl failed
```

My /etc/default/varnish looks like:

```
START=yes
NFILES=131072
MEMLOCK=82000
INSTANCE=$(uname -n)
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:1234 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \ 
             -s malloc,256m"
```

And the vcl is:

```
backend default {
.host = "localhost";
.port = "1234"; 
}

sub vcl_recv {
 if (req.restarts == 0) {
if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
    req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
} else {
    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
}
 }
 if (req.request != "GET" &&
   req.request != "HEAD" &&
   req.request != "PUT" &&
   req.request != "POST" &&
   req.request != "TRACE" &&
   req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
   req.request != "DELETE") {
     /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
     return (pipe);
 }
 if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
     /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
     return (pass);
 }
 if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
     /* Not cacheable by default */
     return (pass);
 }
 return (lookup);
 }

 sub vcl_pipe {
 # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
 # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
 # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
 # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
 # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
 # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
 return (pipe);
}

 sub vcl_pass {
 return (pass);
 }

 sub vcl_hash {
 hash_data(req.url);
 if (req.http.host) {
     hash_data(req.http.host);
 } else {
     hash_data(server.ip);
 }
 return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hit {
 return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_miss {
 return (fetch);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
 if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
     beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
     beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
    /*
     * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
     */
    set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
    return (hit_for_pass);
 }
 return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
 return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_error {
 set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
 set obj.http.Retry-After = "5";
 synthetic {"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
 <title>"} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Error "} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</h1>
 <p>"} + obj.response + {"</p>
 <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
 <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
 <hr>
 <p>Varnish cache server</p>
</body>
</html>
"};
 return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_init {
return (ok);
}

sub vcl_fini {
return (ok);
}
```

Could someone please tell me why I'm getting this error and how I can fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In default.vcl need change:

```
backend default {
.host = "localhost";
.port = "8080"; 
}
```

or another port

Varnish should look on apache or nginx (backend)

Answer (score 0):

The output is clear:

> Connection failed (localhost:1234)

So make sure you can access varnish CLI on that host:port combination and you haven't started the daemong with a "secret" (-S) option:

```
varnishadm -T localhost:1234
```

You can find out if the Varnish daemon is actually attached to the port issuing:

```
netstat -lpn
```

And the daemon options in use with:

```
ps aux | grep varnish
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same port for Varnish CLI and for your default backend.
Change the Varnish admin interface port (if your webserver are listening on 1234)

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6081 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \ 
             -s malloc,256m"
```